# Convert UTC time to javascript date

Tags: javascript

I am using highcharts a JS library it gives me the time of a point in UTC format: 2592000000 which should correlate to a date somewhere in 2011.

How do I get the actual date of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE

Checkout [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). It extends the Date.parse method and Date.parseExact method and you can specify a format string.

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation

---

Check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)...

> A lightweight javascript date library for parsing, manipulating, and formatting dates.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix

Comment: Thanks for the link, think thats giving me the same value that I already have, any idea how I turn that into a date? (the one in 2011)

Comment: @Baconbeastnz... can you show the code that made it work for you?

Comment: Hey Hristo, haven't got it working yet, just fixed a different date issue I was having now getting onto this, I'll post it up when I Can

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var date = new Date(2592000000);
alert(date);
```

Comment: that outputs a date from 1970..?